# Java - Gson parsing nested within nested

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to interact with an API, and the response format (from what I've read) seems to be poorly structured.  I've found a google groups reply to a somewhat similiar problem [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/a8a183e4fc3e1f6a?pli=1), but I'm having trouble implementing a Response class to handle the Gson.fromJson.  Is there an example I'm missing that's out there?

```
{

"response":{
    "reference": 1023, 
    "data":{
        "user":{
            "id":"210",
            "firstName":"john",
            "lastName":"smith",
            "email":"pocahontas@gmail.com",
            "phone":"",
            "linkedid":{
                "id":"238"
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The JSON objects `{}` can be represented by a `Map<String, Object>` or a Javabean class. Here's an example which uses a Javabean.

```
public class ResponseData {
    private Response response;
    // +getter+setter

    public static class Response {
        private int reference;
        private Data data;
        // +getters+setters
    }

    public static class Data {
        private User user;
        // +getter+setter
    }

    public static class User {
        private String id;
        private String firstName; 
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String phone;
        private Linkedid linkedid;
        // +getters+setters
    }

    public static class Linkedid {
        private String id;
        // +getter+setter
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
ResponseData responseData = new Gson().fromJson(json, ResponseData.class);
```

Comment: Why GSON requires inner class?

Comment: @Chetan: That's not a GSON requirement.

Comment: This gives a NPE indeed