# Creating a listview from a nested JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview, gson

I have a JSON file that I fetch from the internet which contains schedule data for a TV channel. Nested within that file, alongside lots of metadata, is info about each broadcast (i.e. each programme) and below is a sample of that file:

[For ease of understanding, I recommend this visual representation of the below JSON instead (click on the **Viewer** tab on the JSON viewer).](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcnews/programmes/schedules/today.json)

```
{
"schedule": {
    "service": {
      "type": "tv",
      "key": "bbcnews",
      "title": "BBC News Channel"
    },
    "day": {
      "date": "2013-11-15",
      "has_next": 1,
      "has_previous": 1,
      "broadcasts": [
        {
          "is_repeat": false,   <=== This is the 1st broadcast programme
          "is_blanked": false,
          "pid": "p01ks4z3",
          "start": "2013-11-15T03:45:00Z",
          "end": "2013-11-15T04:00:00Z",
          "duration": 900,
          "programme": {
            "type": "episode",
            "pid": "b03hdhhp",
            "position": null,
            "title": "15/11/2013",
            "short_synopsis": "All the latest sports news and results from around the globe.",
            "media_type": "audio_video",
            "duration": 900,
            "display_titles": {
              "title": "Sport Today",
              "subtitle": "15/11/2013"
            },
            "first_broadcast_date": "2013-11-15T03:45:00Z",
            "ownership": {
              "service": {
                "type": "tv",
                "id": "bbc_news24",
                "key": "bbcnews",
                "title": "BBC News Channel"
              }
            },
            "programme": {
              "type": "brand",
              "pid": "b0121xvw",
              "title": "Sport Today",
              "position": null,
              "expected_child_count": null,
              "first_broadcast_date": "2011-06-13T02:45:00+01:00",
              "ownership": {
                "service": {
                  "type": "tv",
                  "id": "bbc_news24",
                  "key": "bbcnews",
                  "title": "BBC News Channel"
                }
              }
            },
            "is_available_mediaset_pc_sd": false,
            "is_legacy_media": false
          }
        },
        {
          "is_repeat": false,  <=== This is the 2nd broadcast programme
          "is_blanked": false,
          "pid": "p01ks4z4",
          "start": "2013-11-15T04:00:00Z",
          "end": "2013-11-15T04:30:00Z",
          "duration": 1800,
          "programme": {
            "type": "episode",
            "pid": "b03hdhhs",
            "position": null,
            "title": "15/11/2013",
            "short_synopsis": "Twenty-four hours a day, the latest national and international stories as they break.",
            "media_type": "audio_video",
            "duration": 1800,
            "display_titles": {
              "title": "BBC News",
              "subtitle": "15/11/2013"
            },
            "first_broadcast_date": "2013-11-15T04:00:00Z",
            "ownership": {
              "service": {
                "type": "tv",
                "id": "bbc_news24",
                "key": "bbcnews",
                "title": "BBC News Channel"
              }
            },
            "programme": {
              "type": "brand",
              "pid": "b006mgyl",
              "title": "BBC News",
              "position": null,
              "expected_child_count": null,
              "first_broadcast_date": "2006-11-01T13:00:00Z",
              "ownership": {
                "service": {
                  "type": "tv",
                  "id": "bbc_news24",
                  "key": "bbcnews",
                  "title": "BBC News Channel"
                }
              }
            },
            "is_available_mediaset_pc_sd": false,
            "is_legacy_media": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Using [the answer to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453006/java-gson-parsing-nested-within-nested), I created a Javabean class like so:

```
private class ScheduleData {

private Schedule schedule;
// create getter & setter

public static class Schedule {
    private Service service;
    private Day day;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class Service {
    private String type;
    private String key;
    private String title;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class Day {
    private String date;
    private String has_next;
    private String has_previous;
    private Broadcasts broadcasts;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class Broadcasts {
    private String is_repeat;
    private String is_blanked;
    private String pid;
    private String time;
    private String end;
    private String duration;
    private OuterProgramme programme;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class OuterProgramme {
    private String type;
    private String pid;
    private String position;
    private String title;
    private String short_synopsis;
    private String media_type;
    private String duration;    
    private String first_broadcast_date;
    private DisplayTitles display_titles;
    private Ownership ownership;
    private InnerProgramme programme;
    // create getter & setter  
}

public static class DisplayTitles {
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class Ownership {
    private Service service;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class Service {
    private String type;
    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String title;
    // create getter & setter
}

public static class InnerProgramme {
    private String type;
    private String pid;
    private String title;
    private String position;
    private String expected_child_count;
    private String first_broadcast_date;
    private Ownership ownership;
    private String is_available_mediaset_pc_sd;
    private String is_legacy_media;
    // create getter & setter
}
}
```

---

**In my activity file, how do I loop through each broadcast node of the fetched JSON and retrieve programme data such as `short_synopsis` or `display_titles` and pass these into a custom listview display?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Define root Json Wrapper class ***ScheduleData.java***

```
public class ScheduleData {
    private Schedule schedule;

    public Schedule getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }
}
```

**2)** Define its properties as seperate public classes:

**2.a)** ***Schedule.java***

```
public class Schedule {
    private Service service;
    private Day day;

    // TODO: create other getters & setters if you need
    public Day getDay() {
        return day;
    }
}
```

**2.b)** ***Service.java***

```
public class Service {
    private String type;
    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String title;

    // TODO: create getters & setters if you need
}
```

**2.c)** ***Day.java***

```
public class Day {
    private String date;
    private int has_next;
    private int has_previous;
    private Broadcast[] broadcasts;

    // TODO: create other getters & setters if you need
    public Broadcast[] getBroadcasts() {
        return broadcasts;
    }
}
```

**2.d)** ***Broadcast.java***

```
public class Broadcast {
    private boolean is_repeat;
    private boolean is_blanked;
    private String pid;
    private String start;
    private String end;
    private int duration;
    private Programme programme;

    // TODO: create other getters & setters if you need
    public Programme getProgramme() {
        return programme;
    }
}
```

**2.e)** ***Programme.java***

```
public class Programme {
    private String type;
    private String pid;
    private String position;
    private String title;
    private String short_synopsis;
    private String media_type;
    private int duration;
    private String first_broadcast_date;
    private DisplayTitle display_titles;
    private Ownership ownership;
    private Programme programme;

    // TODO: create other getters & setters if you need
    public String getShort_synopsis() {
        return short_synopsis;
    }

    public DisplayTitle getDisplay_titles() {
        return display_titles;
    }
}
```

**2.f)** ***DisplayTitle.java***

```
public class DisplayTitle {
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;
    // create getter & setter
}
```

**2.g)** ***Ownership.java***

```
public class Ownership {
    private Service service;
    // create getter & setter
}
```

**3)** Define an `AsyncTask` and call json service. Get result as stream and set its value to a `ScheduleData` instance using [gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list). (I assume you know how to call json service on android, but if you don't it is a 5 min googling issue.)

```
HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
InputStream source = getResponseEntity.getContent();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
ScheduleData scheduleData = gson.fromJson(reader, ScheduleData.class);
```

**4)** Now you have a `ScheduleData` instance. It is filled by service's json response.

```
Schedule schedule = scheduleData.getSchedule();
Day day = schedule.getDay();
Broadcast[] broadCastArr = day.getBroadcasts();
// TODO: use your broadCastArr in an adapter
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting my list view adapter working. This is the code in my activity to call the adapter. Is is correct?        `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListView);`
        `ScheduleListViewAdapter adapter = new ScheduleListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_schedule_list, broadCastArr);`
        `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: There is noting wrong with it. (if your listView is not null and you have implemented ScheduleListViewAdapter correctly)