# How to extract property from JSON embedded within JSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

This is the JSON String I am getting back from a URL and I would like to extract `highDepth` value from the below JSON String.

```
{
  "description": "",
  "bean": "com.hello.world",
  "stats": {
    "highDepth": 0,
    "lowDepth": 0
  }
}
```

I am using GSON here as I am new to GSON. How do I extract `highDepth` from the above JSON Strirng using GSON?

```
String jsonResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

// parse jsonResponse to extract highDepth
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233542/parse-a-nested-json-using-gson

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169754/parsing-nested-json-data-using-gson

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453006/java-gson-parsing-nested-within-nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a pair of POJOs

```
public class ResponsePojo {    
    private String description;
    private String bean;
    private Stats stats;  
    //getters and setters       
}

public class Stats {    
    private int highDepth;
    private int lowDepth;
    //getters and setters     
}
```

You then use that in the `RestTemplate#getForObject(..)` call

```
ResponsePojo pojo = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ResponsePojo.class);
int highDepth = pojo.getStats().getHighDepth();
```

No need for Gson.

---

Without POJOs, since `RestTemplate` by default uses Jackson, you can retrieve the JSON tree as an `ObjectNode`.

```
ObjectNode objectNode = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ObjectNode.class);
JsonNode highDepth = objectNode.get("stats").get("highDepth");
System.out.println(highDepth.asInt()); // if you're certain of the JSON you're getting.
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But suppose if I don't need any POJO in my use case. I just need to extract only that `highDepth` value - How would I do that then?

Comment: Man, you saved my week, I figured out that I can use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode as a field of my POJO if I don't want to parse it or if it is dynamicly changes and should be parsed manually by Gson for example.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [JSON parsing using Gson for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java), I would write something like

```
JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResponse);
JsonObject rootObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject statsObject = rootObject.getAsJsonObject("stats");
Integer highDepth = Integer.valueOf(statsObject.get("highDepth").toString());
```