# JSON Nested Objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm working with a JSON file that has nested objects like this,

```
{
  "LocId":99,
  "typeId":99,
  "name":"foo",
  "parentId":99,
  "geoCode":
  {
    "type":"bang",
    "coordinates":
    [{
       "latitude":99.0,
       "longitude":99.0
    }]
  }
}
```

I created a container to hold the JSON file in a class like this,

```
public class Location_JSON {

   private LocId id;

   // +getter+setter

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return id.toString();
   }

   public static class LocId {

       private Long locId;
       private Long typeId;
       private String name;
       private Long parentId;
       private GeoCode geoCode;

       // +getters+setters

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "{\"locId\":" + locId
                   + ", \"typeId\":" + typeId 
                   + ", \"name\":" + name
                   + ", \"geoCode\":" + geoCode.toString() + "}";
       }

   }

   public static class GeoCode {

       private String type;
       private Coordinates coordinates;

       // +getter+setter

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           //return "{\"type\":" + type + "}";
           return "{\"type\":" + type
                   + ", \"coordinates\":" + coordinates.toString() + "}";
       }

   }

   public static class Coordinates {

       private Double latitude;
       private Double longitude;

       // +getter+setter

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "[{\"latitude\":" + latitude
                   + ", \"longitude\":" + longitude + "}]";
       }

   }

}
```

To test that everything works I read in the JSON object as a string like this,

```
String str = "the JSON string shown above";

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

Location_JSON locations = new Gson().fromJson(br, Location_JSON.class);

System.out.println(locations.toString());
```

This produces a NullPointerException!

I implemented two of the Deserializer solutions found in this SO post,
[Get nested JSON object with GSON using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit) but it still created the same null error.

According to this SO post,
[Java - Gson parsing nested within nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453006/java-gson-parsing-nested-within-nested) what I have should be close.

I tested my code without the nested objects i.e., I erased the nested objects from both the string and the Location_JSON container, and everything worked. So I believe this is a JSON nested object problem.

**UPDATE:**

If you're looking at this post I just want to point out that I accepted **chengpohi**'s answer because it solved my initial question and chengpohi was the first to provide an answer. I did however have a second problem that I did not discover until after this question was solved. **Sachin Gupta** provided a working solution to my second problem. If you're using this post please check out BOTH answers down below. Thank you.

Comment: How do you think the JSON you've provided should be mapped to an instance of the POJO type you've defined?

Comment: This is my first time using JSON so I'm not really sure what that means.

Comment: Ignore the posts for a second. You have a JSON object, with a complex data structure. You have a POJO type with a complex data structures. Which parts of the JSON map to which parts of the Java object?

Comment: I thought it worked by matching the key from the key:value pair to the variable name. So if I have a variable named foo and a key value pair of foo:12 then my variable foo would get the value 12.

Comment: Good. So your JSON, at the root, is a JSON object with properties with keys `locId`, `name`, `typeId`, etc.  You're using Gson with `new Gson().fromJson(br, Location_JSON.class);`, mapping that whole structure to a `Location_JSON` instance. Where are those properties in that class?

Comment: I just saw you edit this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27633777/3299397 :)

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying now. I need to provide the object that houses the initial properties/keys. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Location_JSON locations = new Gson().fromJson(br, Location_JSON.class);
```

it should be:

```
LocId locations = new Gson().fromJson(br, LocId.class);
```

You get `NullPointerException`, because your `LocId` have not be initiliazed. Your JSON is a object of `LocId`.

and your JSON:

```
"coordinates":
    [{
       "latitude":99.0,
       "longitude":99.0
    }]
```

should be:

```
"coordinates":
    {
       "latitude":99.0,
       "longitude":99.0
    }
```

Comment: I think that worked....but now it's saying "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 97 path $.geoCode.coordinates"

Comment: Ugh! This is an API response I don't have the ability to modify the JSON.

Comment: I think I can use this SO post to fix the rest of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628096/json-array-to-java-objects.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in above answer, you have to use `LocId` class as primary one.

now for `java.lang.IllegalStateException` you can modify `GeoCode` class to use array of `Coordinates` class. like :

```
public static class GeoCode {    
private String type;
private Coordinates []coordinates;

// +getter+setter

@Override
public String toString() {
return "GeoCode [type=" + type + ", coordinates=" + Arrays.toString(coordinates) + "]";
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me tremendously with the IllegalStateException. I wish I could accept two answers...